# Quick Look for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7

I am looking for a free program that replicated the built-in [Quick Look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look) feature on OSX for Windows 7.

This is basically a quick glance of the file/folder selected when you press <kbd>space</kbd>. By quick glance, I mean:

For folders:

- folder size
- number of files?
- image of thumbnails inside folder

For files:

- file size
- *preview of file*

By preview of file, I mean, if it's a picture, show the picture. If it's a word document, show a preview of the document etc.

Requirements:

- free
- features above
- runs on Windows 7 64-bit

[image]

Comment: See this http://superuser.com/questions/49115/looking-for-quick-view-quick-look-program-for-windows

Comment: Most of What you're looking for is already available in windows explorer. You can see a preview of the file in the preview pane (images, mp3, video, office files or pdf's if Adobe's reader is installed); the size is available as a column in details view or in the Details Pane in the bottom. For folders the properties window (alt+Enter or `Properties` from the context or file menu) can get you the total size and number of files. You're only missing the preview of files contained in a folder.

Comment: @frozenkoi Yes, but the thing is, I want everything in one place, easily accessible. Also, Windows does not show previews of file in a folder *and files themselves* (eg. a text file preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seer](http://1218.io), "A quick look tool for Windows", acts just like the Quick Look on OS X.

And Seer is more powerful and faster.

Comment: Completely forgot to follow up on this! It's great! Thank you :) This is the best I've seen, so I've accepted it :)

Comment: a better one is coming soon~~ I did a lot of work about it.  : )

Answer (score 2):

Try **[QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/)**:

- freeware
- the folder previews are shown by clicking on a button that appears when hovering with the mouse a folder
- no preview for MP3 or documents (except plain `.txt`)
- preview for images and videos (may require codec pack installation?)
- adds some other features to Windows Explorer which some may (not) want - like tabbed browsing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but really looking for a program that more-or-less replicates Quick View, especially the SPACEBAR toggle

Comment: Original QTTabBar seems to be discontinued, but [this fork](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) is still under active development.

Comment: Well I didn't want my bounty to go to waste so I will award it to this answer. Thanks for your help on this question though. :)

Answer (score 1):

[maComfort](http://leonardo.re/macomfort/) seems to be what you are looking. One of the feature is

> Quicklook
>   Preview files like you would on Mac. Just hit space and a Quicklook preview of the file will be shown.

Available as a Freemium.

Comment: This only show the details of the file. If I pressed space on a picture it doesn't display it/preview it like in mac.

Comment: It also doesn't show preview for files, such as `.txt` files. There is no slideshow for pictures. It only shows file size and path. Good option though...

Comment: I am not sure what lzumi or ᔕᖺᘎᕊ are having issues with, but I can do what they seem to not be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the current best option would be [QuickLook](http://pooi.moe/QuickLook/). It works in various file managers including Directory Opus, it is free (GPL v3), and it is under active development.